# Nebensatz - verschwurbelte Passivkonstruktion

Tags: sentence-structure

Beim Editieren einer anderen Frage bin ich an eine Grenze gestoßen. Folgender Satz.

> Diese Frage scheint bereits woanders diskutiert worden zu sein.

Ich habe kurz gezweifelt, aber ich denke, das ist richtig. Als Nebensatz jedoch bin ich mir absolut unsicher.

> 1. Da diese Frage bereits woanders diskutiert zu sein worden scheint, ...
> 2. Da diese Frage bereits woanders scheint diskutiert worden zu sein, ...
> 3. Da diese Frage bereits woanders diskutiert worden zu sein scheint, ...

Der erste klingt für mich am besten (das soll nicht heißen "gut"), aber die Verb-Reihenfolge ist absolut unlogisch.

- Ist ein Nebensatz hier überhaupt möglich und wenn ja wie?

Comment: Die dritte Version scheint mir richtig zu sein, sowohl nach Sprachgefühl als auch Grammatik (finites Verb ans Ende, Rest unverändert).

Comment: Mit scheint 1 Käse und die anderen beiden ok. `diskutiert worden` sollte zusammen bleiben, oder?

Comment: Als Alternative: "Da diese Frage anscheinend bereits woanders diskutiert wurde"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Am Beispiel von

> Da diese Frage wahr zu sein scheint, ...

erkennt man, dass der Satzbau in Ordnung ist. Nun setzt man an Stelle von `wahr` die Wortgruppe `bereits woanders diskutiert worden`, die hier die Stellung des Adjektivs - also den Zustand vom Wort `Frage` - einnimmt, und bekommt Version 3 der angefragten Möglichkeiten.

Comment: +1 für's analytische Denken :)

Comment: Ich stimme @Em1 zu... super überzeugend argumentiert :)

Comment: +1, ich würde gerne so antworten können!